# Do cantrips count as zero level spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In [pathfinder magic](http://paizo.com/prd/magic.html) an arcane spellcaster can memorize a lower level spell into a higher level spell slot if they wish.

Eg use a 3rd level spell slot to memorise a 2nd level spell.

Does this include [cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Cantrips)?

> Arcane Spells Wizards, sorcerers, and bards cast arcane spells.
>   Compared to divine spells, arcane spells are more likely to produce
>   dramatic results.
>
> Spell Slots: The various character class tables show how many spells
>   of each level a character can cast per day. These openings for daily
>   spells are called spell slots. A spellcaster always has the option to
>   fill a higher-level spell slot with a lower-level spell. A spellcaster
>   who lacks a high enough ability score to cast spells that would
>   otherwise be his due still gets the slots but must fill them with
>   spells of lower levels.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing prohibiting you from preparing a 0-level spell (cantrip) in a higher level slot [1]. The rules state the spells are "cast like any other spell", with the notable exception that "...they are not expended when cast and may be used again" [2]. Per the RAW, this would equally apply even if it was prepared in a higher level slot. Cantrips don't have any restrictions otherwise (and the only distinction from non-cantrip spells is, in fact, a benefit).

The question I have though, and this is admittedly just out of curiosity, but why would you want to waste a valuable higher level slot on something as mundane as a cantrip?

**SOURCE**

[1]
http://paizo.com/prd/magic.html ("Preparing Wizard Spells")

> A spellcaster always has the option to fill a higher-level spell slot with a lower-level spell.

[2]
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Cantrips

> Wizards can prepare a number of cantrips, or 0-level spells, each day, as noted on Table: Wizard under “Spells per Day.” These spells are cast like any other spell, but they are not expended when cast and may be used again. A wizard can prepare a cantrip from an opposition school, but it uses up two of his available slots (see below).

Comment: Just pipped the other post for clarity and layout. Thanks!

Comment: It actually might be a very good idea.  If a low level character can only cast 1 or 2 first level spells, he may get more utility out of a cantrip.  Magic missle's guaranteed damage is good but its not like there are minions (4th ed) in pathfinder.

Comment: Also nice at higher level; 1st level spells are beginning to get a bit pointless and a few extra cantrips can be nice.

Answer (score 16):

Cantrips are definitely 0-level spells, and that should mean you can memorise them in a higher -level slot. However, the real question from there is - are they used when cast, if memorised in a higher level slot?

The definition of cantrips comes from the Cantrip Class Abillity, as shown below

> Cantrips: Wizards can prepare a number of cantrips, or 0-level spells, each day, as noted on Table: Wizard under “Spells per Day.” These spells are cast like any other spell, but they are not expended when cast and may be used again. A wizard can prepare a cantrip from a prohibited school, but it uses up two of his available slots (see below).

This doesn't really clarify one way or the other, but it certainly seems to indicate that it's the level of the spell that defines a cantrip, which leads me to believe you could still recast a cantrip memorised in a higher-level slot.